# Why is left joining in my query so much slower than lazy loading?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine2 with Symfony2. I have a query in my UserRepository that looks like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('s', 'p', 'a', 'fp', 'ea', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('u.subscription', 's')
        ->leftJoin('s.plan', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('u.applications', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('u.facebook_pages', 'fp')
        ->leftJoin('u.editable_apps', 'ea')
        ->leftJoin('u.coupons_redeemed', 'c')
        ->where('u = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ;

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

According to the Symfony profiler, this one query takes around **`63 ms`**. When I comment out the `a` and `fp` left joins and instead get the user object and do `$user->getFacebookPages()` and `$user->getApplications()`, I have three queries which take around **`3.50 ms`**.

How can I make the query with left joins as fast as lazy loading the related entities?

Comment: Are you sure lazy loading will be faster? Can you post a query plan?

Comment: Are you sure you get all the data with lazy loading? Or the difference is due to the fact that with with lazy loading you ignore `editable_apps` and `coupons_redeemed`?

Comment: @Vatev, the query created with the `createQueryBuilder` creates a query selecting * from all tables. The `FROM` is user table and then a `LEFT JOIN table ON ..` for each of the other tables.

Comment: @n.1 I get all the data with lazy loading too. Then it just runs additional queries. The queries do differ that they aren't `LEFT JOIN`s, they are instead queried directly on the (otherwise left joined) table and have the user id in `WHERE` when it's a FK and and when there is a join table it's `INNER JOIN`ed and join table's user id is in the where clause. Perhaps the left joins just have greatly poorer performance?

Comment: Have you tried with `innerJoin()` instead of `leftJoin()`? Is it quicker?

Comment: @n.1 if I use `innerJoin()` it doesn't find the user because some connections (I guess `coupons_redeemed` in this case) are empty sets.

Comment: So try to use `innerJoin()` for all joins except for the `coupons_redeemed`?

Comment: @n.1 the thing is that any one `applications`, `facebook_pages`, `editable_apps` can also be empty. `coupons_redeemed` returns very few rows if any.

Comment: Maybe you need to create the indexes for the FKs in the database.